# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osmnx'

Tags: python, tkinter, pip, package

I have a github repo containing two files in the same repository. guimain.py and mapdraw.py. We're basically using tkinter and some other packages to make a GUI and for this we need maps of different places.

mapdraw.py imports osmnx just as `import osmnx as ox` and guimain utilizes an object created there.
It imports it with `from mapdraw import drone_map`.

I'm running in git bash on Windows 10, I'm using python 3.7.3 and here is my package list that I mostly downloaded from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely or I used pip install when there wasn't a problem with the pip installation:

```
Package         Version
--------------- ----------
attrs           19.3.0
certifi         2020.4.5.1
chardet         3.0.4
click           7.1.1
click-plugins   1.1.1
cligj           0.5.0
cycler          0.10.0
decorator       4.4.2
descartes       1.1.0
Fiona           1.8.13
GDAL            3.0.4
geopandas       0.7.0
idna            2.9
kiwisolver      1.2.0
matplotlib      3.2.1
munch           2.5.0
networkx        2.4
numpy           1.18.2
osmnx           0.11.4
panda           0.3.1
pandas          1.0.3
pip             20.0.2
pyparsing       2.4.7
pyproj          2.6.0
python-dateutil 2.8.1
pytz            2019.3
requests        2.23.0
Rtree           0.9.4
Shapely         1.7.0
six             1.14.0
urllib3         1.25.8
wheel           0.34.2
```

The error I'm getting is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "guimain.py", line 11, in <module>
    from mapdraw import drone_map
  File "C:\Users\Alexa\OneDrive\Documents\Universitet\DD1393\Kod\GUI\MVK-Saab\GraphicalInterface\mapdraw.py", line 10, in <module>
    import osmnx as ox
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osmnx'
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: Can you run `python3 -m pip freeze` to check that the modules have been installed for the same version of python as you are running? (Presuming that you are running your module using the `python3` command, otherwise use the same command as used when you execute your code).

Comment: When I run your command I get the following.

```
$ py -m pip freeze
cycler==0.10.0
kiwisolver==1.2.0
matplotlib==3.2.1
numpy==1.18.2
pandas==1.0.3
pygame==1.9.4
pyparsing==2.4.7
pypiwin32==223
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2019.3
pywin32==224
six==1.14.0
```

Comment: So the modules haven't been installed for the same version of python. For the ones installed via `pip`, you could install them using `py -m pip install MODULE`. For the others, I guess you installed them using wheels? Are they definitely for the same sub-version of python as you are using?

Comment: Alright I got it working now! Thank you for your help dspencer! :)

Redownloading them with ```py -3 -m pip install MODULE``` they all showed up when I then did ```py -3 -m pip freeze```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the modules installed via `pip`, you need to check that they were installed using the version of `pip` associated with the version of `python` (or `py`) used to run your code. You can find the installed modules using:

```
python -m pip freeze
```

If this doesn't match your output above, then you will need to install the modules again for the version of `python` that you are using. You can do this using:

```
python -m pip install MODULE_NAME
```

For the modules installed using wheel packages, you need to make sure to install the binary packages for your specific subversion of python, which you can check using `python --version`.